# Force import line formatting on python script

Tags: python, lint, pylint

I see there are two ways of declaring a big import clause:

```
from lib.backends.my_lib import (
    MyClassA, MyClassB, MyClassC, MyClassD
)
```

and

```
from lib.backends.my_lib import MyClassA, \
    MyClassB, MyClassC, MyClassD
```

I personally prefer the first one and I'd like to force this pattern into pylint.

Is there any way of doing so?

Comment: Your preferred style is backed by PEP-8.

Comment: I also don't see `pylint` complaining about the first style.

Comment: My point is that my team is using both patterns in our project nowadays and I'd like to force a single pattern.

Comment: @chepner pylint doesn't seem to complain about none of those, but I'd prefer it to. I seems better to make the pylint force a single format in our project